# Application in IIS tries to load web.config twice

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-10

I have an ASP.NET application hosted via local IIS that has suddenly began throwing web.config errors saying that values cannot be declared twice.  However, the web.config file does not have duplicates.  After chasing the error for a while, it appears that IIS is attempting to load the web.config file twice.

- Deleting/recreating the application node in IIS does not help.
- Uninstalling/reinstalling IIS does not help.
- Deleting/recreating the default website in IIS does not help.
- Deleting all ASP.NET cache files does not help.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

This problem was caused by a corrupt ApplicationHost.config file in IIS (typically in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config)
When I viewed the file, there was an orphaned entry from an application that had previously been deleted via the IIS Manager GUI that had been hosted at the same URL.  This orphaned entry was not displayed in the IIS Manager GUI, and could not be deleted that way.  It pointed to be a previously branched version of the same application, hosted in a different local folder, and IIS tried to load its web.config file which was similar enough to the actual web.config file to causing the duplicate errors.

Manually removing the orphaned entry in a text editor and restarting the app pool solved the problem.

Comment: This problem is caused by Visual Studio when clicking the "Create Virtual Directory" button in the web application's properties dialog on the "Web" tab.  If i determine more specifics, I'll postback and add them.

Comment: That fixed my problem too.  Thank you so much!